Seeking ShiVa 2.0 and lib S3DClientNative_Android.a 64bit
I am having trouble building a 64-bit game using ShiVa Engine. I have previously used ShiVa Engine 32bit for game development, but now I want to switch to 64bit. However, ShiVa Engine is no longer being developed and supported.
After some research, I found out that in order to build a 64-bit game with ShiVa Engine, I need the lib S3DClientNative_Android.a 64bit. However, this lib is only available in ShiVa 2.0.
Therefore, I would like to ask everyone:
•   Does anyone have ShiVa 2.0?
•   Does anyone have lib S3DClientNative_Android.a 64bit?
I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.
Additional information:
•   I have tried searching for ShiVa 2.0 and lib S3DClientNative_Android.a 64bit online but have not been able to find them.
•   I am willing to pay for ShiVa 2.0 and lib S3DClientNative_Android.a 64bit.
